Return[] in Recursive Functions
Here is the pseudocode I am using to demonstrate the problem.
foo[VARS_]:= Block[{vars=VARS},
Dummy code...
Do[
  If[var[[1]]]==True
    ,
    Modify vars...
    vars[[3]]=foo[vars];
    Continue[];
    ,
    Return[0];
  ];
More dummy code...
,
{ii,vars[[2]]}
];
Return[vars[[3]]];
];

When I was writing the code, I had in mind that if the var[[1]]]==True condition is not satisfied, I will get 0 when running foo. Since Return[0] exits the next control structure which is Block, it will not produce 0 when conditions are met, since foo is a recursive function. What I want is to terminate the recursive evaluation of foo.
A few details.

I cannot use Abort because the output of foo will be used later inside an evaluation cell.
I don't want to tag the output of Return[0], since these tags has to be checked in several places, which is tedious.
Currently I use the Catch&Throw solution where I just replace Return with Throw. This is not an ideal solution as there are other places in the code where Throw is used. The output of Catch[foo[VARS]] has to be checked every time it is used. It is not cumbersome and easy to implement. Still...

The question is how to have Return[] not to exist the nearest control structure, but to exit foo completely, i.e. stop the recursive evaluation of foo and generate some expected output, if conditions are met. Is there a way to change the behavior of Return[]?
Thanks in advance.

@xzczd thanks for a quick answer. I used Return[vars[[3]], Block] and it produced the correct result. However, the recursion continued until the end which is not ideal.

Return exists only the innermost control structure and not the whole function. You may set a dummy variable inside the Do[..] and Break to leave the Do[..]. Then you can check the dummy and use Return outside the Do[..]

You can use a tag (2nd argument) in Throw[] and multiple tags in Catch[] (via patterns) to control the flow. Module[{tag}, Catch[Do[... Throw[res, tag]...], tag]].

@DanielHuber thanks. As I explained, I don't want to use such tagging. Besides, if I use Break it will break out of Do loop but not from foo, i.e. recursion won't stop this way. I will have to set up many If-control points which I am trying to avoid. And naturally, I want to understand better Mathematica.

@MichaelE2 thanks for your answer. I somehow missed such a possibility, i.e. tags in Throw. Before I was just checking the exact form of the output.
